# onNavigationItemSelected() returns null menuItem on OnePlus One

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, menuitem, android-navigationview

I have an Application with a Navigation View. I haven't had any problem in most of the mobiles I have tested the application with, but it crashes when it's installed in a "OnePlus One" mobile model with Android version 5.x, when I click into a MenuItem in the Navigation View.

I have taken a look and I get a "**menuItem -> null**" when I click on any item. (navigationView is not null)

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
        {
            selectItem(menuItem);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I select an option:

```
 if (menuItem.getTitle() == getResources().getString(R.string.information))
        {
            fragment = new InformationFragment().newInstance();
            title = getString(R.string.information);
        } else if (menuItem.getTitle() == getResources().getString(R.string.coaches))
        {
            fragment = new CoachesFragment().newInstance();
            title = getString(R.string.coaches);
        } else if (menuItem.getTitle() == getResources().getString(R.string.my_teams))
        {
            fragment = new TeamsFragment().newInstance();
            title = getString(R.string.my_teams);
        } else if (menuItem.getTitle() == getResources().getString(R.string.all_players))
        {
            fragment = new AllPlayersFragment().newInstance();
            title = getString(R.string.all_players);
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_body, fragment)
                .commit();
```

With the next dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Environment:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'xxx.xxxx.xxxx'
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.2'
```

I have researched into the net but I haven't found the solution, also I have changed it to 23.1.1 but nothing...

Log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:414)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:449)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:441)
   at com.rcassociats.tsunamis.activity.MainActivity.selectItem(MainActivity.java:223)
   at com.rcassociats.tsunamis.activity.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:48)
   at com.rcassociats.tsunamis.activity.MainActivity$2.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:186)
   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:150)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:84)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:308)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

[MainActivity.java](http://pastie.org/10560492)  <--- COMPLETE CODE

Comment: please update your .java file  here or logcat output

Comment: Thanks Hitesh for your alert

Comment: please update your complete .java file code so hope it will help us to find out exact exception

Comment: http://pastie.org/10560492